# vertically scrolling html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a long HTML list of say, 30 items. I would like to display this list in a vertical space that is only tall enough to accommodate about 5 of them. The list should automatically scroll vertically through the items (like a news ticker), but there are button to pause the scrolling and move to the next or previous items in the list. When the scrolling has reached the end of the list, it should restart at the beginning.

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin recommendation that can provide this functionality. I have a couple of other requirements, which are not absolutely necessary, but very desirable:

- can accommodate list items of different heights
- does not depend on jQuery-UI

The entire list will be loaded when the page is displayed, so I **don't** need to be able to load the list items via AJAX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen this:

http://buildinternet.com/2011/02/totem-a-vertical-ticker-jquery-plugin/

I used it recently and it worked great. Seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: Although I didn't see it mentioned in the docs, it does 'restart' when the last node is reached.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it's a simplest solution without using additional jQuery plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/5q3Bv/4/

Comment: The transitions are very jarring and I would like to be able to display more than one at-a-time